# sim7600 MQTT connection loss GNSS enables

Tags: sim7600

I am using Lilygosim7600e-h to get the GPS location. After getting it, I am connecting to the internet using pppos_example using gsm internet (TCP) to send the GPS data to the mqtt. but signal drops when GNSS is enabled; it will not work both at the same time, either internet or GNSS. I am also referring to getting this work done, but I dont know why in an espidf environment.

i am trying to work both gsm/gnss together in espidf using sim7600e-h. expecting gnss data send to the mqtt.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue with is Modem.
I used the inbult MQTT stack. whenever the GPS is enabled, I will looose the MQTT connection.
Just got tired and drop the project.
It will be of interest if anyone can help out.